# Dart - Invoke base class constructor with constant parameter

Tags: dart

I want to do this:

```
  class BaseClass {
      int param1;
      String param2;
      BaseClass(this.param1, this.param2);
   }

  class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
      int param3;
      ChildClass(super.param1, super.param2 : "Constant", {this.param3});
  }
```

Does not compile, can't figure out the syntax or if it's possible at all.
How?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by https://dart.dev/language/constructors#super-parameters:

> ```dart
> class Vector3d extends Vector2d {
>   final double z;
>
>   // Forward the x and y parameters to the default super constructor like:
>   // Vector3d(final double x, final double y, this.z) : super(x, y);
>   Vector3d(super.x, super.y, this.z);
> }
> ```

So `Vector3d(super.x, super.y, this.z)` is syntactic sugar for:

```dart
Vector3d(final double, final double y, this.z) : super(x, y);
```

Therefore your child constructor can be:

```dart
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  int? param3;

  ChildClass(int param1, {this.param3}) : super(param1, "Constant");
}
```

(Note that `param3` either must have a default value or must be nullable if you want it to be optional, or you must instead mark it `required`.)